# React resize even listener isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, addeventlistener

On resize even listener is not being triggered.

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.containerRef.current.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.containerRef.current.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  handleResize() {
    console.log("handleResize");
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container ref={this.containerRef}>
            <Body />
          </Container>
          <ShadowTop show={this.state.top} />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
  }

}
```

--

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 760px) {
    position: absolute;
  }

  margin-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.percent}%;
  margin-top: -webkit-calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  margin-top: -moz-calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  margin-top: calc(${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);

  height: ${({ theme }) => Math.abs(100 - theme.header.height.percent)}%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);
  height: calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.header.height.pixel}px);

  position: fixed;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: ${({ theme }) => 100 - theme.sidebar.width.percent}%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);
  width: calc(100% - ${({ theme }) => theme.sidebar.width.pixel}px);


  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: auto;
`;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Am trying to detect when the `div` aka `Container` a `styled-components` element has changed size.

Comment: DOM elements don't have a resize event; only the window does.

Answer (score 6):

The `resize` event is triggered on `window`, not on individual elements. This is because the `resize` event is meant to handle viewport resize, not content resize. To detect content size changes you can use [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

There are a lot of ways you can incorporate this into your React project. Here is a example similar to what you have in the question:

```js
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.ulRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = { todoList: [] };
    
    // Binding methods to the current intance is only needed if you pass
    // the method as an argument to another function and want acces to the
    // `this` keyword in the method.
    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
    this.addTodoItem = this.addTodoItem.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ulObserver = new ResizeObserver(this.handleResize);
    this.ulObserver.observe(this.ulRef.current);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.ulObserver.disconnect();
  }

  handleResize(entries, observer) {
    console.log("handleResize", entries);
    // ...
  }
  
  addTodoItem(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      todoList: [...state.todoList, formData.get("todo-item")],
    }));
  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.addTodoItem}>
          <input name="todo-item" />
          <button>add</button>
          {" "}(or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
        </form>
        <ul ref={this.ulRef}>
          {this.state.todoList.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainContainer />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

There might also be libraries out there that help you combine `ResizeObserver` and React. But it doesn't hurt to understand what is happening under the hood.

---

For those looking for a more modern function component solution:

```js
const { createRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

function MainContainer() {
  const ulRef = createRef();
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
  
  const addTodoItem = useCallback(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    setTodoList(todoList => [...todoList, formData.get("todo-item")]);
  }, []);
  
  const handleResize = useCallback(function (entries, observer) {
    console.log("handleResize", entries);
    // ...
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(function () {
    const ulObserver = new ResizeObserver(handleResize);
    ulObserver.observe(ulRef.current);
    return () => ulObserver.disconnect();
  }, [handleResize]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addTodoItem}>
        <input name="todo-item" />
        <button>add</button>
        {" "}(or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
      </form>
      <ul ref={ulRef}>
        {todoList.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<MainContainer />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> resize events are only fired on the window object

You can read more about [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

It should be:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
}
```

You can add `debounce` to **handleResize** to make it less often.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't work for me. So what I am trying to do is detect when the height of the content inside the container changes

Comment: @Nikk The `resize` event is specifically to handle viewport resize, not content resize. Use [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Comment: @Nikk I've added my comment as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71173787/3982562) with an example how you could use this in combination with React.